# Add two encr/decr keys in a byte[] keyValue

Tags: java, arrays, byte

I am trying to implement the Diffie Hellman algorithm to exchange keys for my crypto and i am having a problem with assigning the totals to my array. This is what i have tried:

```
private static final String privatekey = "password";
private static final String publickey = "aloha";
private static final byte[] b = privatekey.getBytes();
private static final byte[] c = publickey.getBytes();
private static byte[] keyValue;

public void createCommonKey(){
    for(int i=0; i<b.length; i++){
        keyValue[i]=(byte)(b[i]+c[i]);
    }

    System.out.println(keyValue);
}
```

When i try to run in it gives me a nullPointerException. I understand why i get that since the two keys don't have the same length as arrays. And that's what i'm asking, what do i need to correct to make this work. At first i tried adding each array individually and the take those two values and add them to the keyValue array but that didnt work since the values where, well, valus and not arrays. I thought about adding the arrays elements in the array[0] and the putting 0 from elements [1] to [length] but i am not sure that is correct and since i'm dealing with bytes i don't know if 0 actually has a byte value. So i want to hear you ideas and i am asking for you help.

Comment: You don't initialize `keyValue` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The `NullPointerException` is not caused by the potentially different lengths of the arrays, but by the fact that `keyValue` is `null`. You might add

```
public void createCommonKey(){
    keyValue = new byte[b.length]; // <-- This line
    for(int i=0; i<b.length; i++){
    ...
```

to make this error disappear.

But still, the arrays have different lengths, which will cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when `b.length` is greater than `c.length`. I don't know the details of Diffie-Hellman, but a simple approach *might* be to let the indices "wrap" when they become too large:

```
public void createCommonKey()
{
    int max = Math.max(b.length, c.length);
    keyValue = new byte[max];
    for(int i=0; i<max; i++)
    {
        int ib = i % b.length;
        int ic = i % c.length;
        keyValue[i]=(byte)(b[ib]+c[ic]);
    }
}
```